# Javascript Regex: how to remove string before > and including >

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like so

```
item[3]>something>another>more[1]>here
hey>this>is>something>new
.
.
.
```

I would like to produce the following for each iteration indicated by each new line

```
item[3]>something>another>more[1]>here
something>another>more[1]>here
another>more[1]>here
more[1]>here
here
```

Another example:

```
hey>this>is>something>new
this>is>something>new
is>something>new
something>new
new
```

I would like a regex or some way to incrementally remove the **furthest left string up to >**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it using[`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
var str = 'item[3]>something>another>more[1]>here',
    delimiter = '>',
    tokens = str.split(delimiter); // ['item[3]', 'something', 'another', 'more[1]', 'here']

// now you can shift() from tokens
while (tokens.length)
{
    tokens.shift();
    alert(tokens.join(delimiter));
}
```

See also: [`Array.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift).

[**Demo →**](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/rHeAU/)

Answer (score 2):

```
myString.replace(/^[^>]*>/, "")
```

Answer (score 1):

To iterate through the cases, perhaps try this:

```
while (str.match(/^[^>]*>/)) {
  str = str.replace(/^[^>]*>/, '');
  // use str
}
```